# The remote server returned an error (400)

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I got bad request using the following Code :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://xxxxxxx");
            request.Headers.Add("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded ";
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] buf = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("sssssssssssssss");
            request.ContentLength = buf.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

}
```

am I missing something in the configuration

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `https://xxxxxxx` is valid in the browser and the SSL certificate is valid, you may need to pass correct headers like `User-Agent` if you haven't already.

Comment: what's useragent please

Comment: User-Agent is basically to tell the web server who you are. It is something that is set by your browser. User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 should suffice.